# ThreeJS export from Maya 2017 causing problems

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, maya

I've got a problem exporting from Maya to Three.js

I have Maya 2017 on a Mac and ThreeJS downloaded from the site - very recently. Initially I downloaded a version of three and the .min version ( seems to be Revision 57 ) seemed to work fine. I was using

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

I then read this had been deprecated, so I swapped to using `mesh = new.Three.Mesh ( geometry, materials )`. With three.js it failed completely - no model rendered and no errors generated. It renders the stage or whatever that's called in threejs, but nothing else. If I generate models in script outside the json loader they render as normal, but that's not really helpful. I need the json to load and render.

I went back and tried re-installing the three export. In the meantime I think the version was changed, now I cannot get any joy out of either three.min.js or three.js to instantiate a model.

I've read around a few solutions and tried triangulating the models with no effect - I still get an empty stage and no errors generated. I created a very simple model - just a cube thats triangulated, and didn't get any joy. I looked at the examples on the ThreeJS site for the JSON loader - but they weren't much help either.
Without resorting to stepping through the JSONLoader parser to look at the JSON does anyone have any bright ideas? I'm not even sure where I can find the correct form for the exported data.

Comment: As is, there's not enough specific information here for someone to help you. For example, when it "failed completely," what happened? Was there an error message? The other times that you couldn't get any joy, what did you get? Also try to narrow your question to one case.

Answer (score 0):

When I say I didn't get any joy I mean there was no model rendered and as far as I can tell no errors. I of course used console to check the contents of the arrays and for example materials is correct as far as I can see.
As I mentioned I reverted to as simple a model as possible, a single cube trianulated. The Json
Is very short I could post that?
The basic problem is just no model showing. I've checked the lighting in case it was hidden and put other objects generated outside the json to see if I can see it but I think it's just not being instanciated and doesn't throw an error?

I think my goal is to get a simple json file from maya that I then import into threejs and use mesh ( geometry, materials ) to generate a model that I can manipulate.

Comment: how about some code instead of answering your own question :)

Comment: Ok - so new user, of a forum - got it wrong. I can't seem to delete the answer, and repost what should have been a further comment. Should I delete the question and start again?

Comment: Could you also suggest the best place to display the JSON as, even though thats very small, its still too big for a comment?

I have created a JSFiddle of the HTML etc here, http://jsfiddle.net/weymouthwookie/8wfcr1cr/ - but thats not really helpful as its clearly not failing on that side of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I will add an answer now, as I have one.

The basic problem is that the ThreeJS JSON export for Maya does not seem to work - the export is not right, ThreeJS doesn't like something about that output - I can't get it to work anyway.
What does work is using the conversion utility that changes an OBJ file into a JS file, which can then be loaded using the same code. So first you output an OBJ file from Maya - easy enough. The conversion utility can be found in the threes download folder in utils>converters>obj>convert_obj_three.py
You have to use console - Im on a Mac, and easiest to place a copy of the file in your working folder then once you have navigated to the correct working folder with all your files in the console, use this line,

python convert_obj_three.py -i myFile.obj -o myfile.js

This resulting JS file can then be loaded into threeJS using

var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

```
//load a resource
jsonLoader.load(

//resource URL
'myFile.js',

//Function when resource is loaded
function ( geometry, materials ) {

    var material = materials[ 0 ];
    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( object );

}
);
```

Next problem is that the thing doesn't show - the material is black. You can only see it if something is in front of it, or you use a grid or something. It took me a while to figure this out by checking the console to see that the material was being loaded but it shows as black - no matter what I did with the lighting which I assumed was the problem. I found that adding a material colour magically switched it on, and so add the line material.color.setHex( 0xffffff ); before the scene.add( object ); line.